# Pylance - Type of pandas method is partially unknown

Tags: python, pandas, pylance

If I try to validate code that uses pandas methodes with pylance in strict mode, I get a validation error.

```
import pandas as pd

ser: pd.Series[float] = pd.Series([.1, .2, .5, .3])
print(ser.max())
```

Pylance in strict mode returns the error:

> Type of "max" is partially unknown

Am I doing something wrong?
Can I avoid this error without switching pylance to basic mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to pyright [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md), one can turn off this specific check by creating `pyrightconfig.json` file in the same project folder with the next content:

```
{
    "reportUnknownMemberType":"none",
}
```

So you can be still in strict mode, but with one type of checks disabled.