# Pylance says "Type of 'read_csv' is partially unknown"

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pylance

I'm trying to run the following code in VS Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

But it shows the problem:
[image]

This didn't happen before.

The other solutions I saw didn't seem to work.

This same problem happens with virtually any package I import. A few of them are:
[image]

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71751434/pylance-type-of-pandas-method-is-partially-unknown), but it didn't work.

Comment: This problem cannot be repeated. Have you tried to use pre-release version or other version of pylance.

Comment: Have you tried replacing Pylance with Jedi as python language server?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I tried older, latest, and pre-release version of pylance, didn't work.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I also installed the 'jedi' and 'Language jedi' VS Code extension, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting VS Code by deleting all the content in `settings.json` and replacing it with a simple `{}` helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me resolved the error.

In VSCode `settings.json` delete the following line:

`"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict"`

Comment: This is not a solution, you're just avoiding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update your [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) version can solve this according to [the pre-release on github](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#2022851-31-august-2022-prerelease).

You can also switch to the pre-release version in extension store.

[image]

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. Thanks though.